# The have_selector fails in an RSpec test but page renders correctly and the tag is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webrat

I'm working my way through the Rails Tutorial book by Hartl and I'm completely stuck on one of the tests. The test (right from the book) is very simple:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController do
render_views
describe "GET 'show'" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
    end
    ...
    it "should include the user's name" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
    end
end
```

The test fails with the following error:

`UsersController GET 'show' should include the user's name
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
       expected following output to contain a <h1>Steve T</h1> tag:...`

The page renders properly in the browser. Here is a snipped from the HTML source rendered by the browser:

`<section class="round">

    <h1>
        <img alt="Steve T" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/..." />
        Steve T
    </h1>
</section>`

I can even add a call to: `print response.body` in the controller spec and it will output the tags properly.

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

**UPDATE** - It seems like we have identified a potentially significant item: The HTML in the rspec test failure message is missing the body tag everything inside it.

`1) UsersController GET 'show' should include the user's name Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name) expected following output to contain a <h1>Steve T</h1> tag: <!DOCTYPE html> <html><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"> <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Steve T</title> </head></html> # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:33:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Does anyone know why, if the page in the browser includes the `<body>` tags and the inner content and if `print response.body` shows the  content, why would the error message skip it?

Comment: Note sure, but I think have_selector matches exactly? In your case, the H1 contains an embedded IMG. I suppose it would work if that IMG was not there. Tried it? And `have_selector` is a webrat matcher, I believe. You might want to try `response.should contain(@user.name)`. Or this *might* work: `response.should have_selector('h1 img', :content => @user.name)`.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening, as far I have experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that syntax mistake in the partial that loads my style sheets was essentially commenting out all the body tag content. The question is why Firefox 3 rendered the HTML anyway. I actually solved the problem inadvertently by upgrading to Firefox 4. In Firefox 4, the body of the page didn't render and the debugging tools led me to the erroneous markup

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when working through the Rails Tutorial. I forgot to include 'render_views' below the top 'describe' statement, which was causing the 'have_selector' test to fail.

Comment: This is a great thing to check, it's tripped me up a couple of times

Answer (score 3):

My solution was in installing [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara),
include in your Gemfile

```
group :development do
 gem 'capybara'
end
```

then do

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

than edit you code to

```
response.body.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
```

now run your tests. It should work

Answer (score 1):

The test is failing because the h1 is wrapped around a `<img />` so the content isn't correct and the test fails.

you could do something like this:

```
it "should include the user's name" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should have_selector('h1')
    response.body.should contain(@user.name);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I modified the view file to put the image and name in separate h1 tags. Still getting the same error. The code rendered in the browser is now: `<h1><img alt="Steve T" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/...?size=50" /></h1>
<h1>Steve T</h1>
`

Comment: it's because all h1s content is expected to be `@user.name`, is there any reason for the `<img>` to be in a `<h1>`?

Comment: I just modified the view again to remove the image from the h1. Still no luck. Here is the HTML:
`<img alt="Steve T" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/..." /> <h1>Steve T</h1>`     Thanks again. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: now that you've done that you can use `response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)` again

Comment: It gave the same error. I used the following code to dump the response and the @user.name to the terminal just to make sure that the variable was initialized properly.. the tag is in the html and the name prints properly between the asterisks.   `it "should include the user's name" do
 get :show, :id => @user
 print response.body
 print '***'
 print @user.name
 print '***'
 response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
 end`

Comment: is @user.name in the test and @user.name in the view the same?

Comment: Yes. Here is the output: `...    
<img alt="Steve T" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/a..." />
<h1>Steve T</h1>
...
***Steve T***`

Comment: can you post the full rspec failure.

Comment: `  1) UsersController GET 'show' should include the user's name
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
       expected following output to contain a <h1>Steve T</h1> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html><head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
       <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Steve T</title>
       </head></html>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:33:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: hmm, your layout isn't rendering the `body` tag does your layout.html.erb file have `<%= yield %>` somewhere in it?

Comment: Interesting... Yes, there is a `<%= yield %>` in layout.html.erb and the `body` does render in the browser and `print response.body' returns text. I wonder what is causing the discrepancy.